# Special validation multiple phone numbers with regex

Tags: javascript, regex, validation, numbers

I want to validate multiple phone numbers like +905369865222-625 can starts with "+" and can slice with "-" using regex.

Comment: Please show us what did you try to code !

Comment: Please provide more details.

Answer (score 0):

After a little bit of practise, I reach this point:

```
^\+?[0-9-]+(?:;\+?[0-9-]+)*$
```

this regex can accept the numbers like:

+91-9743574891;+1-570-456-2233;+66-12324576
+91-9743574891;+1-570-456-2233;6612324576

Now i want to add a limitation to every single phone number.

Answer (score 0):

^+?[0-9-]{6,24}(?:;+?[0-9-]{6,24})*$

this is enough for me